# Using induction to prove a description of a formal language

Tags: induction, formal-languages

One of my tasks is to proof that something is correct or incorrect using induction. Since I am from Germany and don't know the right word in English I do my best to give all necessary info. We are talking about "words" and amounts of words which are in so called alphabets.

> Let $\Sigma \overset{\Delta} = \{a, b\}$ and $S_1 \overset{\Delta} = \{a^n \mid n \in \Bbb N\}$. Prove using induction that $$\forall w \in \Sigma^* . w \in S_1 \to \big( w = \lambda \lor (\forall \ 1 \le i \le |w| . (w)_i = a) \big) .$$

How to prove that? Any help is upvoted, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is obvious, there is nothing to prove here: if a word belongs to $S_1$, then it is either the empty word, or it is a concatenation of "$a$"s, by the mere definition of $S_1$.

Comment: yes but how can I use induction anyway to proof that? even though it is obvious?

Comment: There is no need to use induction. By definition, the letters of the word $a^n$ are all equal to $a$.

Comment: @RayofCommand: There is one serious reason why induction makes no sense here: induction is used to prove properties that depend explicitely on some $n \in \Bbb N$. Note, though, that $S_1$ does *not depend* on $n$ (the $n$ inside its definition is a "running variable", or a "dumb variable", i.e. nobody depends on it). The person who gave you this exercise was somewhat superficial.